# On which stage booked Ride with Uber can be cancelled and patched

Tags: uber-api

We are implementing Uber API Ride integration for one client for USA region.

Uber is providing following Ride Status - 
Processing, no_drivers_available, Accepted, Arriving, in_progress, driver_canceled, rider_canceled and Completed

I want to confirm on which stage booked Ride with Uber can be cancelled and patched.

As per my understanding-

1) We can request cancellation of existing Uber Ride request only if ride status is in Accepted, Arriving or in progress. 
Need to confirm if rides with Processing or no_drivers_available status can be cancelled or not?

2) Uber Patch API allows to change only destination for existing Ride request only if existing ride status is in Accepted, Arriving or in progress/in route. 
It does not make sense to call Uber Patch API for rides which are in Processing, no_drivers_available, driver_canceled, rider_canceled or in Completed status.

Answer (score 0):

Uber ride request can be canceled in two ways:

1. `Rider Canceled` - can be done in following statuses:

   - processing
   - accepted
   - arriving
   - in_progress
2. `Driver Canceled`:

   - accepted
   - arriving
   - in_progress

`Uber Patch API` allows changing the destination for existing Ride request in following statuses:

- accepted
- arriving
- in_progress